# My library pane is missing, how to get it back

Tags: xcode, xcode10, utility

I have already searched in the shortcuts in the Xcode preferences but I couldn't find a way to get it back.

My current interface:

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Xcode 11 and 12**: Click the "plus" button at the top, left of the "Show/Hide Code Review" button. Alternatively, use "View > Show Library" or hit Shift-Cmd-L.

**Xcode 10**: Click the "square in a circle" button at the top, left of the "show standard editor" button. Alternatively, use "View > Libraries > Show Library" or hit Shift-Cmd-L.

Comment: and the old library is missing ?

Comment: From the release notes: "Library content has moved from the bottom of the Inspector area to an overlay window, which can be moved and resized like Spotlight search."

Comment: ... and which disappears whenever you add just 1 object to your storyboard. So good luck building complex views from scratch people!!! &@#ing Apple...

Comment: When you use Cmd-Alt-Shift-L to open the Library, the window stays open.

Comment: ugh.. i grow more tired of Apple's BS everyday.. what's the benefit of that change?

Answer (score 7):

XCode  11

Click the button highlight in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it is buried under some other window - particularly if you've dragged xcode to a different monitor. The library shows up on the monitor that xcode was opened onto, and it won't appear atop something like a full screen video playback.