# Item selector not showing in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi guys I'm trying to add an item to my viewcontroler (as shown) but the item attribute selection bar is not showing. There is nowhere for me to drag the buttons from. Not sure if this is a glitch or if I'm an idiot and not seeing the obvious. [Here's the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPO0m.png)

Comment: Are you using Xcode 10? if yes press Shift+Command+L to show viewLibrary form where you can drag view components.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My library pane is missing, how to get it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566356/my-library-pane-is-missing-how-to-get-it-back)

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 10 you can use **COMMAND+SHIFT+L** shortcut to get the View Library. Or you can click the icon in top right corner mentioned in the below image.

[image: ViewLibrary]

It will show up as a movable pop-up like below.
[image: ViewLibrary]

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I just updated to Xcode10 and didnt know

Comment: Take my upvote, idk who gives you a downvote. Your answer was little bit earlier :) Have I nice day.

Answer (score 1):

It Moved to the top right corner of the XCode as shown on the picture.
**NB** To see the button you must switch to Interface Builder. It now works only in IB context

[image: It Moved to the top right corner of the XCode]

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I just updated to Xcode10 and didnt know

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10. Use Shift+Command+L or click it here.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I just updated to Xcode10 and didnt know